# find points on the curve such that

Tags: calculus

find points on the curve $y=e^{x^2+2x}$ at which the tangent line to the curve passes through the point $(1,0)$.

I know I should

1. find derivative of $y$
2. find $y'(1)$ which gives slope
3. using point slope formula find equation of tangent line
4. find point of intersection of curve and tangent line

But by their graph it is clear that the line is not tangent. So please guide me

Comment: Please post you work: (1)What is y'?  (2) what is yy'(1)? (3) What is the point slope formula.  ....

Comment: I have had a look at your previous questions : I am surprized that they all have the same aspect : "I should do that" followed by one or two sentences followed by "could you help me". This is not the way you will progress in mathematics.

Comment: Now a mathematical remark: due to the strict convexity of the curve of the function (check that $f''(x)>0$) and to the fact that (1,0) is exterior to the curve, there are necessarily two solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(h,k)$ be on the curve such that $k=e^{h^2+2h}$, then at $P$,$\frac{dy}{dx}=(2h+2)e^{h^2+2h}=2k(h+1)$. Next the slope of the tangent joining P and $A(1,0)$ is $m=\frac{k}{h-1}=2k(h+1) \implies 2h^2-2=1 \implies h=\pm \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$ So the required point $P$ on the curve is given as $$P(\pm \sqrt{3/2},e^{3/2\pm\sqrt{6}}).$$

See the following figures for $h<0$ and $h>0$, respectively

[image]

[image]

Comment: The question, as it is now, does not respect the general lines for a "valid" question... Instead of giving an answer for such a question, please consider asking first for some context / details in a comment to the question.

Comment: Thanks, I did it up now.

Comment: See the comments I just made to the OP.